# declarativeNetRequest update rules

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As described into the documentation I'm trying to update `declarativeNetRequest` rules of a chrome extension. From the docs:

> **updateDynamicRules**
>
> chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(array of integer ruleIdsToRemove, array of Rule rulesToAdd, function callback)
>
> Modify the current set of dynamic rules for the extension. The rules with IDs listed in ruleIdsToRemove are first removed, and then the rules given in rulesToAdd are added. This update happens as a single atomic operation: either all specified rules are added and removed, or an error is returned. These rules are persisted across browser sessions and across extension updates. Any ids in ruleIdsToRemove that are not present will be ignored. Note that static rules specified as part of the extension package can not be removed using this function. Note: MAX_NUMBER_OF_DYNAMIC_RULES is the maximum number of dynamic rules an extension can add.

It's not clear what is intended for dynamic rule. This api will rely on a static rule set that can't be modified until an extension is updated and the method described into the documentation says that the rules shipped with the extension will not be removed from the function.

My question is, how I really can update the rules after I get new rules from an online api? The declarativeNetRequest api didn't provide any method to do this, all the methods provided will not be useful for this scope.

Comment: Have you figured how to use chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules() api correctly?

Answer (score 14):

After I spent some time figuring out how the `chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules()` API works, I ended up with this solution. `blockUrls` is an array variable that holds all blocked websites/URLs.

```js
blockUrls.forEach((domain, index) => {
  let id = index + 1;

  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    addRules: [{
      "id": id,
      "priority": 1,
      "action": { "type": "block" },
      "condition": { "urlFilter": domain, "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"] }
    }],
    removeRuleIds: [id]
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you adding and removing the same rule id at the same time?

Comment: @RaedCHAMMAM To avoid duplicate ids.

Comment: Wouldn't that remove the rule you just added since it has the same id?

Comment: @RaedCHAMMAM I'm not so sure, but I think it would not.

Comment: @RaedCHAMMAM The docs say "The rules with IDs listed in ruleIdsToRemove are first removed, and then the rules given in rulesToAdd are added," so he is just making sure that he won't get a conflict with an ID that is already in use.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are using TypeScript and @types/chrome, you should replace `"block"` with `chrome.declarativeNetRequest.RuleActionType.BLOCK` and `"main_frame"` with `chrome.declarativeNetRequest.ResourceType.MAIN_FRAME`, because they are defined as enums in the .d.ts file.

Comment: What is ```blockUrls``` and why are you doing a ```foreach```
 ?

Comment: @LetsGoBrandon blockUrls is a declared variable, and it loops through all URLs by using foreach to add or update rules.

Comment: But why doing a +1 ?

Comment: @LetsGoBrandon Usually index starts at 0, so it adds 1 each loop. It is also incremented by 1 to avoid duplicate ids.

Answer (score 3):

Create an array with all your new rules. Get the old rules and replace them all with the new rules.

```js
const newRules = [];
blockUrls.forEach((domain, index) => {
  newRules.push({
    "id": index + 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": { "type": "block" },
    "condition": { "urlFilter": domain, "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"] }
  });
});

chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getDynamicRules(previousRules => {
  const previousRuleIds = previousRules.map(rule => rule.id);
  chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: previousRuleIds,
    addRules: newRules
  });
});
```