# Chrome Extensions: chrome.runtime.lastError: Internal error while updating dynamic rules

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

***SOLUTION***: Installed the latest version of chrome. All is well.

I am attempting to set dynamic rules to allow users to manually configure blocked and allowed sites using the declarativeNetRequest api. Specifically the updateDynamicRules method.

I attempt to add a new rule:

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(
  {
    addRules: [
      {
        id: 1,
        action: {type: "allow"},
        condition: {urlFilter: "abc", resourceTypes: ["main_frame"]}
      }
    ]
  },
  () => {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
      console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
  }
)
```

I've disabled all other extensions. I get the lastError: *"Internal error while updating dynamic rules"* I have attempted using another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63789613/declarativenetrequest-update-rules), but arrive to the same, rather vague result.

Has anyone else experienced this?

EDIT: Other things I have tried, in accordance to comments:

- Changing the id of the dynamic rule in question
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the extension

Comment: Do you have a static rule declared via manifest.json with id 1?

Comment: I do have a static ruleset, in which I did have a rule with id 1.

I changed the id of the dynamic rule to an id not contained in the ruleset, and still get the same internal error.

Comment: I have attempted reinstalling by removing the extension and loading it in. Still the same error.

Comment: Might be a bug. Try Chrome Canary or the [latest Chromium snapshot](https://download-chromium.appspot.com). To report the bug use https://crbug.com.

Comment: I've attempted this on the latest version of chrome and it works a charm!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for the comment that helped solve my issue. "Might be a bug. Try Chrome Canary or the latest Chromium snapshot. To report the bug use crbug.com."

Simple installed the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: @JonColeman94 Which version worked for you?

Comment: I'm using `Version 93.0.4577.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and it's working. It doesn't work in `Linux Ubuntu` in the same version chrome.