# chrome extension : how can get header of request (before or after ) in manifest version 3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I already published an extension in the store
Recently, Google forced us to use manifest version 3
Previously, the program, with the user's knowledge, read certain sites as the header of their requests
In this version, I did not find anything that works so that I can read the header information

Please give me a simple example
Thankful

The previous version I have :

```
manifest.json
```

```
{
   "author": "hoseinx1225@gmail.com",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "/src/js/background.js",
      "/src/js/httpTrackerConstants.js",
      "/src/js/httpTrackerUtils.js",
      "/src/js/httpTrackerOpen.js"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This extension is only available on some job boards.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "my-exteintion",
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://*.linkedin.com/*"
  ],
  "version": "3.0.5",
  "browser_action": {
    "browser_style": true,
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/src/assets/icon.png",
      "32": "/src/assets/icon.png"
    },
    "default_title": "This extension is only available on some job boards."
  },
  "commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+1"
      },
      "description": " This extension is only available on some job boards."
    }
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "/src/html/popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "320": "/src/assets/icon.png"
  }
}
```

```
httpTrackerConstants.js
```

```
const httpTracker = {
  browser: window.browser || window.chrome,
  isFF: window.browser ? true : false,
  PAGE_PATH: "/src/html/popup.html",
  STORAGE_KEY_EXCLUDE_PATTERN: "httpTrackerGlobalExcludePatterns",
  STORAGE_KEY_INCLUDE_PATTERN: "httpTracker_GlobalIncludePatterns",
  STORAGE_KEY_BLOCK_PATTERN: "httpTracker_GlobalBlockPatterns",
  STORAGE_KEY_MASK_PATTERN: "httpTracker_GlobalMaskPatterns",
  STORAGE_KEY_OPEN_ADDON_IN_TAB: "httpTracker_OpenAddonInTab"
};

const FORBIDDEN_HEADERS = ["Accept-Charset", "Accept-Encoding", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Connection", "Content-Length", "Cookie", "Cookie2", "Date", "DNT", "Expect", "Feature-Policy", "Host", "Keep-Alive", "Origin", "Proxy-", "Sec-", "Referer", "TE", "Trailer", "Transfer-Encoding", "Upgrade", "Via"];
const FORBIDDEN_HEADERS_PATTERN = ["Proxy-", "Sec-"];
const DELIMITER_AND = "&";
const DELIMITER_OR = "|";
const DELIMITER_REQUEST_COOKIE = "; ";
const DELIMITER_REQUEST_COOKIE_KEY_NAME = "Cookie";
const DELIMITER_RESPONSE_COOKIE = "\n";
const DELIMITER_RESPONSE_COOKIE_KEY_NAME = "set-cookie";
const STRING_ERROR = "ERR";
const STRING_SPACE = "&nbsp;";
```

```
httpTrackerDomEvents.js
```

```
const trackUrls = {
  urls: ["<all_urls>"]
};


const r = httpTracker.browser.webRequest;

const reqHeadersBlocking = httpTracker.isFF ? ["blocking", "requestHeaders"] : ["blocking", "requestHeaders", "extraHeaders"];

let objHeaders = {}
r.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  function (details) {
     console.log("header of request");
    return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders };
  }, trackUrls, reqHeadersBlocking
);
```

Get the solution to the problem in manifest version 3

Comment: Simply remove `'blocking'` and it'll work.

Comment: @wOxxOm It works, but it doesn't give me the "authorization" headers that I need

Comment: @wOxxOm  tnx bro it's work

Answer (score 1):

In MV3, the webRequestBlocking API is [no longer available](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/#api-blocking), but you can use webRequest and block requests only with declarativeNetRequest.

Also in MV3, Chrome provides a declarativeNetRequest API that allows you to read and modify request headers and response headers using rule sets. For more details see **[declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/)**.

***[Examples of static rules.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#example)***

*[Example of a dynamic rule.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66166440)*

**Fast example - removing CSP header from response:**

```js
//manifest.json
...
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest", 
    "declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess", 
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"
  ],
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_1",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "rules.json"
      }
    ]
  }
...
//rules.json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "responseHeaders": [
        {"header": "Content-Security-Policy", "operation": "remove"}
      ]
    },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "|http*",
      "resourceTypes": ["script", "main_frame", "sub_frame"]
    }
  }
]
```